Add headers on a HTMLAnchorElement when invoke onclick() to make a GET download
I need to download very large files in the Browser, so i need the browser support to download that files. It should look like this:

My problem is that I have to authenticate with a JWT Header. My current solution works but is not secure, i append the jwt token.
private downloadFile(apiPath: string): void {
   this.oidcSecurityService
     .getAccessToken()
     .pipe(take(1))
     .subscribe((token) => {
       const downloadUrl = `${this.apiEndpoint}/${apiPath}?ms-download-jwt=${token}`;
       const link = document.createElement('a');
       link.href = downloadUrl;
       link.click();
     });
 }

Do you have an idea how to add the headers?
This is an angular project.

Why don't you try SAS from azure so that you have a temporary token which expires in a short time and allows you to download, with the exact method you are using.
You have to create an API on your backend that returns the SAS token, then you can trigger the download using this token.

This would be possible in our case as we use a blob storage. But if possible i like to use the current implementation
